# Can't get conv.data to save a parameter in Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

As you can see in: [Console Log from SaveLocation - AskLocationPermission](http://prntscr.com/m7tujy)
it doesn't save the **location_type** to the `conv.data`. While user storage works great I want to correctly use `conv.data` and `conv.user.storage`. You can see in the [Example of conversation](http://prntscr.com/m7tqhp) that the parameter is fulfilled, but it doesn't get saved to the `conv.data`.

How it should work is when user says that he wants to save this location as his home or work, it should look into the `conv.user.storage` if he has home or work fulfilled. If not ask for permission to his location and add it, else it should ask him if he is sure to override it.

```
app.intent('SaveLocation - AskLocationPermission', (conv, {location_type}) => {
    if (storage.isLocationAlreadySaved(conv, location_type)) {
        return fun.talkAsk(conv, i18n.__("LOCATIONS.SAVE_OVERRIDE", location_type))
    }
    storage.setSaveLocationType(conv, location_type);
    console.log("SaveLocation - AskLocationPermission");
    console.log(storage.getLocationType(conv));
    return conv.ask(new Permission({
        context: i18n.__("PERMISSION_LOCATION.SAVE_LOCATION", location_type),
        permissions:
            ['DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION'],
    }));
});

app.intent('SaveLocation - PermissionHandler', (conv, params, permissionGranted) => {
    if (!permissionGranted) return fun.talkAsk(conv, i18n.__("ERROR.PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED", storage.getLocationType(conv)))
    storage.setUserLocation(conv);
    storage.saveLocation(conv);
    return fun.talkAsk(conv, i18n.__("LOCATIONS.SAVE_COMPLETE", storage.getLocationType(conv)))
});

app.intent('SaveLocation - Yes', (conv) => {
    console.log("SaveLocation - Yes");
    console.log(storage.getLocationType(conv));
    return conv.ask(new Permission({
        context: i18n.__("PERMISSION_LOCATION.SAVE_LOCATION", storage.getLocationType(conv)),
        permissions:
            ['DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION'],
    }));
});

app.intent('SaveLocation - No', (conv) => {
    return fun.talkAsk(conv, i18n.__("LOCATIONS.SAVE_DENIED", storage.getLocationType(conv)))
});
```

Storage file:

```
let setSaveLocationType = function (conv, locationType) {
    conv.data.locationType = locationType;
};

let getLocationType = function (conv) {
    return conv.data.locationType;
};

let isLocationAlreadySaved = function (conv, locationType) {
    console.log("isLocationAlreadySaved");
    if (locationType === "work") {
        console.log(getWorkLocationLat(conv))
        return getWorkLocationLat(conv) !== 0.0
    } else if (locationType === "home") {
        console.log(getHomeLocationLat(conv));
        return getHomeLocationLat(conv) !== 0.0
    }
    return false
};

let saveLocation = function (conv) {
    let locationType = getLocationType(conv);
    if (locationType === "work") {
        conv.user.storage.workLocationLatitude = getUserLatitude(conv);
        conv.user.storage.workLocationLongitude = getUserLongitude(conv);
    } else if (locationType === "home") {
        conv.user.storage.homeLocationLatitude = getUserLatitude(conv);
        conv.user.storage.homeLocationLongitude = getUserLongitude(conv);
    }
};


let getWorkLocationLat = function (conv) {
    return conv.user.storage.workLocationLatitude
};
let getWorkLocationLng = function (conv) {
    return conv.user.storage.workLocationLongitude
};
let getHomeLocationLat = function (conv) {
    return conv.user.storage.homeLocationLatitude
};
let getHomeLocationLng = function (conv) {
    return conv.user.storage.homeLocationLongitude
};
```

[How I imagined flow of the conversation for this intent](http://prntscr.com/m7u00c)

Comment: Have you sovled this yet? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have a "setUserLocation" function actually defined, but you try to call it from the "SaveLocation - PermissionHandler" intent handler.

Comment: setUserLocation doesn't have anything to do with it :). That works because it is saved in conv.user.storage, but it should be save in conv.data, because the location changes over time. The problem is about conv.data and function     storage.setSaveLocationType(conv, location_type);